# Summing the length of a varchar

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables that look something like this:

Checkpoint with field:

```
  Checkpoint_id
  Checkpoint_name
```

checkpoint_id is a primary key

Checkpoint_data with fields:

```
Checkpoint_id
sequence_number
data
```

(checkpoint_id, sequence_number) is the primary key

What I want to do, is get the checkpoint_id with its name, but also sum the length of all of the data that is linked via checkpoint_id. For example, I would want to get the length of sequence_number 1, 2, 3 and 4, and then add up the lengths off all of data and return it with the corresponding checkpoint id and name. The data field is a varchar

Comment: Have you tried anything beyond asking here?

Comment: I'm new too SQL and found this neat site http://sqlzoo.net/.  Of course there are others out there but practicing makes perfect.

Comment: I've been testing out my own statements, and I keep getting errors when I try to run them. Came here for some help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT c.checkpoint_id, c.checkpoint_name, sum(length(cd.data))
FROM checkpoint c 
INNER JOIN checkpoint_data cd ON c.checkpoint_id = cd.checkpoint_id
GROUP BY c.checkpoint_id
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT c.checkpoint_id, c.checkpoint_name, sum(length(cd.data))
FROM checkpoint c 
INNER JOIN checkpoint_data cd ON c.checkpoint_id = cd.checkpoint_id
GROUP BY c.checkpoint_id, c.checkpoint_name
```

Comment: I just tried to do this on my tables, but unfortunately it came out with an error: SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: This is the error I've been running into every time I try a new technique for this SELECT statement

Comment: you need to group by all fields that aren't aggregates, so in this case, both the checkpoint_id and checkpoint_name. See the edit

Answer (score -1):

There are two column: first_name, last_name into table employees.

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       LENGTH(first_name)+LENGTH(last_name) 
           as "Length of name" FROM employees;
```